# Contextual Action Bar Back Arrow Color Change

Tags: java, android

I made a Contextual Action Bar which inflates directly while long clicking on some item of the RecyclerView.
I did not create a toolbar or an appbarlayout in the xml file so the app starts without any toolbars or actionbars but when I long click on some item it inflates the contextual action bar.
My problem is, I tried all the possible methods to change the black color of the back arrow in the contextual action bar, but all in vain.

Comment: Do you mean an arrow, when menu items are in group?

Comment: No, the back arrow or back button which is located on the left of the bar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you mean home up button, because it isn't part of contextual menu, it's part of activity menu.

If yes, just put this into your style

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```

`your_drawable` may look like this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        ...
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@android:drawable/your_image"
        android:tint="@color/your_color"
        />
</item>
```

If no, without an image of this arrow I can't tell more.

Comment: thanks, there was a problem with the themes and the matter was so complex to solve. I made another project and changed the theme and now the it is done.